# build is successful but app crashes - React Native

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

I ejected my project from Expo to Bare Workflow by using "expo eject". I am running "npx react-native run-android" and want my app to run on android emulator but the app crashes every time I run it. The build is successful too. Please help

Comment: We won't be able to help you without the actual error or any other context.

Comment: There are not any errors on the console. The build is successful but the app keeps stopping. Before build is successful, I have these two warnings:

Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: If the app actually starts on the emulator, you've made it past Gradle (which handles the native build parts), so those are probably just warnings. Does bundling complete? Something like this on the console: `BUNDLE  ./index.js ▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 20.6% (611/1754)`

Comment: @ShahnihalAlwani did you ever find a way to see the real error? This is happening to me as well and the app is not showing any errors

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the error message or stack trace, otherwise it is hard to detect the exact reason.

Comment: I am using VS Code and I am running "./gradlew.bat installDebug --stacktrace" command for stack trace in android folder of my project. The build is successful but nothing else happens. The app keeps crashing with the error " App keeps stopping"